# Kendo scheduler: Ajax call while dragging an event

Tags: ajax, drag-and-drop, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I was wondering if anyone has a working example of how to make a async ajax call while dragging an scheduler event. I have a horizontal grouping on different locations (resources in the scheduler) and want to update disabled timeslots on every location while using drag and drop. I have tried a few approaches with moveStart, but none of which made any progress.

Here is what I'm trying. The sync function is calling my API controller and should update the scheduler with the new disabled timeslots (slottemplate), but it never gets to the '$ajax'-part of the function (it's like it gets blocked).

```
moveStart: function (e) {
  console.log(e.event);
  selectedActivityId = e.event.activityId;
  syncDisabledTimes(e.event.start);
```

syncDisabledTimes:

```
var asyncAjaxCalls = [];

for (var i = 0; i < selectedLocations.length; i++) {
    asyncAjaxCalls.push(getAsyncCall(selectedLocations[i].locationId, e.event.start));
}

ajaxIsRdy = false;

$.when.apply($, asyncAjaxCalls).done(function () {
    ajaxIsRdy = true;
    var scheduler = data();
    scheduler.view(scheduler.view().name);
});
```

getAsyncCall:

```
    var asyncCall = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/v1/DisabledTimeTableUnits/",
    data: {
        'mode': DisabledTimeTableUnitsMode.OnlyDisabledTimes,
        'filterOnOutsideTimeTableSet': true,
        'filterOnSeasonLimits': true,
        'filterOnOpeningHours': true,
        'filterOnBookinglock': true,
        'filterOnActivity': selectedActivityId === null ? false : true,
        'utcTime': true,
        'start': moment(_date).startOf('week').isoWeekday(1).toISOString(),
        'end': moment(_date).endOf('week').isoWeekday(7).toISOString(),
        'locationId': locationId,
        'activityId': selectedActivityId
    }
}).done(function (disabledTimeUnits) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedLocations.length; i++) {
        if (selectedLocations[i].locationId === locationId) {
            selectedLocations[i].disabledTimeSlots = disabledTimeUnits;
        }
    }
});

return asyncCall;
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: I've posted the original code (what I initially wanted it to look like - before I started testing around).

But somehow, today the moveStart worked as suspected. Although I get a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined' error message, but I think this refers to another part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

`MoveStart` will fire once as you start dragging. `Move` will continuously fire as you drag the event around.

However, I would recommend that you perform your server side validation upon the `MoveEnd` event.

Comment: Well. I'm using a slot template to define if a slot is enabled or disabled. This I want to update when an event is started to be dragged, to illustrate where it is possible to move the event. The validation is off course put in the MoveEnd.